# How to wrap C++ code into CLI having tons of float* (representing points)?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli, wrapper

So I have a library with lots of C style functions described as:

```
/// Finds the polygon nearest to the specified center point.
///  @param[in]     center      The center of the search box. [(x, y, z)]
///  @param[in]     extents     The search distance along each axis. [(x, y, z)]
///  @param[in]     filter      The polygon filter to apply to the query.
///  @param[out]    nearestRef  The reference id of the nearest polygon.
///  @param[out]    nearestPt   The nearest point on the polygon. [opt] [(x, y, z)]
/// @returns The status flags for the query.
dtStatus findNearestPoly(const float* center, const float* extents,
                         const dtQueryFilter* filter,
                         dtPolyRef* nearestRef, float* nearestPt) const;
```

I wonder how shall I wrap tham in my CLI wrapper to make callable from C#? Here my main intrest is `const float* center` which is [(x, y, z)] pointer - how to form such in C#, how to get tham out in C#? So in general how to work with `float*` in CLI code to make it avaliable in C# code (in and out)?

Comment: just use `pin_ptr`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7704/Arrays-in-C-CLI

Comment: sometimes you just have to make a native array and copy the values. and vice-versa, create a .net array in the wrapper, fill it and return it with values of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on the two other answers, here's what some actual code may look like

**Poly.cpp** (C++/CLI)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Poly.h"

#include "findNearestPoly.h"

using namespace System;

namespace CStyleArrays
{
    public ref class Poly abstract sealed // "abstract sealed" = static
    {
    public:
        static int FindNearest(Tuple<float, float, float>^ center, Tuple<float, float, float>^ extents,
            [Runtime::InteropServices::Out] Tuple<float, float, float>^% nearestPt) {
                const float pCenter[] = { center->Item1, center->Item2, center->Item3};
                const float pExtents[] = { extents->Item1, extents->Item2, extents->Item3};
                float pNearestPt[3];

                int retval = findNearestPoly(pCenter, pExtents, nullptr /*filter*/, nullptr /*nearestRef*/, pNearestPt);
                // if (retval == success)
                {
                    nearestPt = Tuple::Create(pNearestPt[0], pNearestPt[1], pNearestPt[2]);
                }

                return retval;
        }

        static int FindNearest(cli::array<float>^ center, cli::array<float>^ extents, cli::array<float>^% nearestPt) {
        if ((center->Length != 3) || (extents->Length != 3) || (nearestPt->Length != 3))
            throw gcnew ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

            const pin_ptr<float> pinCenter = &center[0]; // "... if any element of an array is pinned, then the whole array is also pinned ..."
            const float* pCenter = pinCenter;
            const pin_ptr<float> pinExtents = &extents[0];
            const float* pExtents = pinExtents;
            const pin_ptr<float> pinNearestPt = &nearestPt[0];
            float* pNearestPt = pinNearestPt;

        return findNearestPoly(pCenter, pExtents, nullptr /*filter*/, nullptr /*nearestRef*/, pNearestPt);
        }
    };
}
```

Sample C# would be

```
namespace TestCStyleArrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                var center = Tuple.Create(0f, 1f, 2f);
                var extents = Tuple.Create(10f, 20f, 30f);
                Tuple<float, float, float> nearestPt;
                CStyleArrays.Poly.FindNearest(center, extents, out nearestPt);
            }

            {
                var center = new[] { 0f, 1f, 2f };
                var extents = new[] { 10f, 20f, 30f };
                var nearestPt = new float[3];
                CStyleArrays.Poly.FindNearest(center, extents, ref nearestPt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to add to @Serious's post, the example function prototype may be:

```
dtStatus findNearestPoly(array<float> ^center, 
                         array<float> ^extents, 
                         array<dtQueryFilter> ^filter,
                         [out] dtPolyRef %nearestRef,
                         [out] array<float> ^%nearestPt) const;
```

for this example, I'm assuming that dtQueryFilter, dtStatus and dtPolyRef are enums or some other directly passable type. If they are classes, then a suitable ref class will need to be created, and the references will include the `^` pointer.

Then, to use the arrays data, you will need to use the `pin_ptr` to lock them from GC:

```
pin_ptr<float> ppf = &center[0];
float *pCenter = ppf;
```

Note, to use the [out] parameter you will have to:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use a simple **cli::array<float>** or a **Tuple<float,float,float>**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383822.aspx

**Tuple** is defined in the **mscorlib** assembly so in both cases you won't pull any additional dependencies.